# Yii2 - fatal error , try-catch not working

Tags: php, yii2, try-catch

i want working with SoapClient in yii2 project. but i need manage error with try-catch. but that not work !

yii2 code example :

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        try{
            new \SoapClient('a',['cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY]);
        }catch(\SoapFault $e){
            echo '***************';
        }
    }
}
```

yii framework output :

> PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL:
>   Couldn't load from 'a' : failed to load external entity "a"

but in test.php(no yii framework) :

```
try{
    new SoapClient('a',['cache_wsdl' =>  WSDL_CACHE_MEMORY]);
}catch(SoapFault $e){
    echo '***************';
}
```

output

```
***************
```

why catch SoapFault not working ? **but in single php script works and printed stars.**

Comment: try catch won't catch a fatal. What error are you getting? (NOTE, unless it's a catchable fatal, but you don't say.)

Comment: seems it's a catchable fatal because try-catch in single php script work but in yii2 framework not working.
what is difference between catchable and no catchable ?

Comment: If I remember, catchable mean fatals are ones you can catch with a custom error handler, non catchable just kill the process then and there no matter what you do.

Comment: yes this is catchabl. why in yii not working ?

Comment: Dunno, you _still_ haven't shown us the actual error.

Comment: error is not important, you run above code and you can see error.my goals is run catch block code in yii framework. Actually above code is correct in own php but in yii framework NO !

Comment: If you don't tell us the error, we can't help. Simple as.

Comment: post edited and i added error and example in two environment.(only php, yii framework)

Comment: Add an extra `catch` block after the first one, i.e. `}catch(SoapFault $e){ echo '***************'; } catch(\Exception $e) { echo '*****************'; }` That should catch it. It looks like yii uses it's own custom error handler and transformed that WSDL error.

Comment: not working !!!! (last result)

Comment: I had the same error. Got it just a bug php https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=47584

Comment: At the same time triggered a fatal error and soapfault. A similar error in laravel https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/6618

Comment: this is not a php bug. in php without yii framewrok wroked but this yii framework not working. my php version is 5.6.3.

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong. If you decide this problem would be cool!

Comment: this is a bug. [https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11772](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11772)

Answer (score 1):

The solution that helped me while I was googling same problem:

```
try {
    $wsdl = 'http://test.com/test/ws/Landing/?wsdl';
    simplexml_load_file($wsdl);
    $short_link = new \SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    var_dump($e);
}
```

source: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11772#issuecomment-413887276

---

If it's nesessary to perform authorization it's possible to use curl

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "{$login}:{$password}");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, $cert_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8"]);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score -1):

you should add

```
define('YII_ENABLE_ERROR_HANDLER', false);
```

it works for me

Comment: please see https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/11772